# Apache+SVN Setup - Receiving Forbidden on some SVN requests but not all

Tags: apache, svn, configuration

Third party provided a server running Apache and SVN. However, I'm setting up the repo and access to it.

**What does work**

I can access the repos in the browser. My problem seems to be in running SVN commands with Versions or in the terminal.

Checking out from trunk or branches with svn+ssh, along with committing to those locations.

**What doesn't work**

Creating branches with the copy command:

```
svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/test -m'creating test branch'
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://svn.server/repo/'; please relocate
```

Accessing the root directory of the repository

```
svn ls  http://svn.server/repo
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://svn.server/repo/'; please relocate
```

I recognize the svn error as a red herring. I see the following in the access log for every failed request:

```
60.60.60.60 - - [25/Apr/2012:09:15:24 -0700] "OPTIONS /Repo HTTP/1.1" 401 478
60.60.60.60 - TravisKs [25/Apr/2012:09:15:24 -0700] "OPTIONS /Repo HTTP/1.1" 301 315
```

Seeing the access logs for my browsers request to the root directory (successful)

```
60.60.60.60 - - [25/Apr/2012:09:47:31 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 936
```

So it seems there is an error in my configuration / security but haven't been able to find it.

My vhost config

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/svn/
    ServerName svn.server
    ServerAlias svn.server

        <Directory "/var/www/svn" >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from all
                Order allow,deny
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/svn.server.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/svn.server.com-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

My SVN config

```
<location "/repo">
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/www/svn/repo

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /var/www/svn/repo/conf/passwd
  Require valid-user
</location>
```

**edit**

Confirming the file permissions on the directories

```
/var/www
[TravisKs@server ~]$ ls -la /var/www/svn
total 10032
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root       4096 Apr 23 16:46 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root   root       4096 Feb 13 14:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 7 apache apache     4096 Apr 20 17:19 repo
[TravisKs@server ~]$ ls -la /var/www/svn/repo/
total 1180
drwxr-xr-x. 7 apache apache    4096 Apr 20 17:19 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root      4096 Apr 23 16:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache    4096 Apr 20 15:44 conf
drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache apache    4096 Apr 20 17:19 dav 
drwxr-sr-x. 6 apache apache    4096 Apr 24 19:10 db
-r--r--r--. 1 apache apache       2 Apr 20 14:18 format
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache    4096 Apr 20 14:18 hooks
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 1167874 Apr 20 14:34 import_log.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache    4096 Apr 20 14:18 locks
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache     229 Apr 20 14:18 README.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seems to stem from conflicts between VirtualHost and SVN. I reconfigured my httpd.conf file, removing the virtual host and just keeping the location directive:

```
<location "/svn">
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
  SVNListParentPath on

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /var/www/svn/repo/conf/passwd
  Require valid-user
</location>
```

Next steps will be creating and using a auth file in a proper location. At this point we can navigate the entire SVN repository through the browser and function normally in console commands and the Versions client.